# Mi programa me manda a otra ruta que no le especifique (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laragon

En una vista tengo los siguientes botones:

```
<a class= "btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right" style="margin-left: 10px" href="/libros">
    <i class="fa fa-book"></i> Libros
  </a>
  <i></i>
  <a class= "btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right" href="/imagenes">
    <i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i> Imagenes
  </a>
```

que nos lleva a las rutas:

```
Route::get('libros', 'InvestigacionController@libros'); 
Route::get('imagenes', 'InvestigacionController@imagenes');
```

el controlador es este:

```
public function imagenes()
{
    return view('Investigaciones.imagenesInvestigacion');
}
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function libros()
{
    return view('Investigaciones.librosInvestigacion');
}
```

El cual regresa una vista muy simple:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al principio me regresaba bien la vista de imagenes y libros, sin embargo, deje el proyecto por unos dias y aproveche para guardar el proyecto en drive usando Backup and Sync from Google. (no se si tenga que ver) pero hoy di click al boton de libros y resulta que me genera otra ruta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No va a /libros sino /public/libros y obviamente me da un 404.
he modificado la ruta de muchas manera y me regresa al mismo lugar, creí que sería el .htaccess, pero no se realmente, el archivo esta así:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Si hago inspección en chrome, veo que la ruta es distinta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A pesar de que cambie a:

```
<a class= "btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right" style="margin-left: 10px" href="{{ route('libros.listado') }}">
    <i class="fa fa-book"></i> Libros
  </a>
```

Comment: no,no necesito indicar public para ir a una carpeta que esta en public, pero yo no quiero ir a public, doy en el href= /libros pero para ir a la ruta Route::get('libros', 'InvestigacionController@libros');

Comment: de ahi al controlador, y funcion libros() que me regresa la vista librosInvestigacion

Comment: no puedes acceder a la carpeta /public/libros porque no existe! lo unico que existe es public/index.php que se encarga de recibir todas las rutas. te recomiendo leer como funciona el patrón `mvc php`

Comment: si entiendo el modelo vista controlador, pero en este caso no quiero ir a public, paso a la ruta en web.php de ahi al controlador que regresa la vista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba haciendo los siguientes cambios:

- No escribas la ruta relativa usando la URL que declaras te en cada ruta
- Mejor cada ruta renombrala con el método [**`name`**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes)
- Usa el helper [**`route`**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes) para que en vez de pasar el string que declaras en el método `get` lo que pases sea el nombre que le diste a cada ruta y esto nos permita tengas la ruta absoluta

Entonces renombra:

```
Route::get('libros', 'InvestigacionController@libros')->name('libros.listado'); 
Route::get('imagenes', 'InvestigacionController@imagenes')->name('imagenes.listado');
```

Ahora cuando en tus etiquetas a invoques la ruta hazlo así:

```
<a href="{{ route('libros.listado') }}">Ir a los libros</a>
```

Comment: hice lo mismo para las dos opciones e imagenes si me regresa bien la vista pero libros no. me regresa un 404 y la ruta es http://proyecto.test/public/libros Segun yo deberia ser como imagenes, es decir http://proyecto.test/libros no?

Comment: edite la publicacion para añadir algo

Comment: Ayer que hice todo esto no me dejaba ir a la ruta correcta, hoy que quise mostrarselo a mis amigos, di click en libros y si me llevo a proyecto.test/libros. no entiendo que paso??? es quiza porque tenia que apagar al laragon y volver a correrlo? sabes que pueda ser?

Comment: @sergeee30 tal vez esto ayude y de ahí puedes continuar investigando http://www.laravelinterviewquestions.com/trick/how-to-clear-cache-in-laravel-odi/#:~:text=In%20Laravel%20php%20artisan%20cache,the%20connection%20to%20the%20database.&text=Further%2C%20on%20shared%20hosting%2C%20you,to%20remove%20your%20database%20cache.